# find the general control function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Determine the general form of $u_0, u_1 ~\text{and} ~ u_2$ if a system of difference equations of the form

$$x_{n+1} = Ax_n  + Bu_n,$$

where:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 2 & 2  \\
  -1 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$

and:

$B = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}$

is to be controlled for $x_0 = 0 ~ to ~ x_3 = [2, 1, 2]^T$ .

Show this target could have been achieved at  $x_2$

Solution
So far I have caculated the controlability matrix to be
$
C
=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&2&2&6&6\\
0&1&-1&0&-3&-2\\
1&0&1&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$
Thus the system is controlable
Now putting Cv=x3 i have the 3 equations
$$
2c+2d+6e+6f=2\\
b-c-3e-2f=1\\
c+e+f=2\\
$$
which i have then put into  row echleon form which i have found to be
$$
a+c+e=2\\
b-c-3e-2f=1\\
c+d+3e+3f=1\\
$$

I proceeded to put these in terms of c,e and f to get the general terms

$a=2-r_1-r_2  ,  b=1+r_1+3r_2  , c=r_1   , d= 1-3r_3-3r_2-r_1  ,  e=r_2   ,  f=r_3,$

however when i substitue this back into my equation to check by doing 
$$x_1=Ax_0+Bu_0, x_2=ax_1+Bu_1, x_3=Ax_2+Bu_2$$

i dont get $x_3=(2,1,2)^T$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/333798  It is a double post.

Comment: @Alex sorry Im still getting to hangs with how to use this, I tried to delete it but am unable to

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding the difference equation with $x_0 = 0$ gives $x_2 = ABu_0+Bu_1$, $x_3 =  A^2 Bu_0+A Bu_1+ B_2u_2$. Recall that each $u_k \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

If we let $R_k = \begin{bmatrix} A^{k-1}B & A^{k-2}B & \cdots &  B\end{bmatrix}$, we can 
write these equations as $x_2 = R_2 \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \end{bmatrix} $, $x_3 = R_3 \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}$. 
It should be clear that setting $\begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $ will result in $x_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} $, and setting $\hat{u} = \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $ will result in $x_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} $.

Hence the general form of $u = \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}$ that reaches the desired $x_3$ is given by $\hat{u} + v$, where $v \in\ker R_3$. Since the last three columns of $R_3$ are clearly linearly independent, it is easy to compute the kernel. Let $R_3 = \begin{bmatrix} Q_1 & Q_2 \end{bmatrix}$, then $\begin{bmatrix}  x \\ y\end{bmatrix} \in \ker R_3$ iff $y = - Q_2^{-1} Q_1 x$. Choosing $x \in \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ gives $\ker R_3 = \operatorname{sp} \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\  0 \\ -3 \\ -1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\  0 \\ -3 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \}$.

The answer is that the control that steers $0$ to $x_3$ is given by:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \alpha_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\  0 \\ -3 \\ -1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} + \alpha_2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\  0 \\ -3 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + \alpha_3 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\  1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
where $\alpha_k$ are arbitrary.

Comment: how would you express the answer? do you add all 4 column vectors together? Thanks!

Comment: @user67298: The answer is above, ie, $\hat{u} + v$, where $v \in \ker R_3$, but I have added an explicit version at the bottom of the answer anyway.